# module was not opening using dynamic feature in android

Tags: android, module, android-app-bundle, android-module

I am working on the dynamic feature module. I uploaded the .aab file into playstore some times app is unable to open the module throwing the error like this.

This is the error getting in logcat:

```
PID: 12715
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 

ComponentInfo{com.testDynamic/com.testDynamic.zco.ZcoActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"com.testDynamic.zco.ZcoActivity"
 on path: DexPathList[[zip file
 "/data/app/com.testDynamic-1/base.apk",
```

This issue here is my code.

This is my Main app manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.testDynamic">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
 
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                   
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my module Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.testDynamic.zco"
    split="dynamiczco">
     
    <dist:module
        dist:onDemand="true"
        dist:title="@string/title_test">

        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />

    </dist:module>
   
    <application>

        <activity

            android:name="com.testDynamic.module.ZcoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
          
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my main gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27

     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.testDynamic"
         minSdkVersion 23
         targetSdkVersion 27
         versionCode 33
         versionName "3.1"
    }

    dynamicFeatures = [":dynamicmodule",":dynamic_feature2",":dynamiczco"]

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    api 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    api 'com.google.android.play:core:1.3.1'

    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    api 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

 }
```

Here is my module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 27
    
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(':app')


 //    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:27.0.+'

}
```

Anyone have an idea about this error please help me to resolve

Anyone help to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show you build.gradle files and manifest for every module, please. And check your ProGuard rules. Also try clean Project and Make Project again.

Comment: please check my gradle and manifest files

Comment: @vallON  is that ok?

Comment: It looks like you made an on-demand module so it won't be served as part of the initial install. Did you trigger the download of that module and wait for the installation to complete?

Comment: it is not only for initial download every time when i try to open the module it is getting crash

Comment: Can you explain clearly what is the problem and what i have to change?

Comment: @gowthami Hi remove `split="dynamiczco"` from you module manifest and try again (including clean Project and make Project). Since the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/dynamic-delivery#dynamic_feature_manifest) says that you should not include or modify this attribute yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi after researching i got the solution. Now the module was downloading without any crash.

I changed the module manifest

```
   <dist:module

        dist:onDemand="true"

        dist:title="@string/title_test">

        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
```

to

```
   <dist:module

    dist:instant="true" 

    dist:onDemand="false"

    dist:title="@string/title_test">

    <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />

</dist:module>
```

It is working fine.
Thank you all